# Purpose of DisableEventSubscriptionsOfChildValues in Catel?

Tags: c#, mvvm, catel

I've done some profiling of an application using the `Catel` framework. There were a lot of calls to `Catel.Data.ModelBase.HandleObjectEventsSubscriptions` and below this method calls none of our code is executed, so I took a closer look at this method call.

I never worked with `Catel`, so i had to look inside the `Catel` code / documentation to see what this code is good for. But I couldn't figure out what this method call is good for. The only thing I found is the possibility to disable this method by setting `Catel.Data.ModelBase.DisableEventSubscriptionsOfChildValues`. We tested this and our application seems to run faster and work as expected, the validation and change notifications are still working.

What is the purpose of `DisableEventSubscriptionsOfChildValues` in `Catel 4.1` and is there a documentation about this switch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event subscriptions are used to be notified of child objects that change. For example, if a model contains a collection, and an object is added to that collection, it can trigger a new validation sequence for you.

For models that don't require validation (or validation of child objects), you can safely turn this off.

We might turn this off by default in the future. If you want that, feel free to create an issue in the official [issue tracker](http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker).

Comment: I don't know whether this should be disabled by default, but this switch should be mentioned in the "[Performance considerations](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Performance+considerations)" chapter of the Catel documentation. Regards

Comment: The cool thing is that the documentation is editable for everyone ;-)